# How to keep ConEmu in current directory after a run command?

Tags: console, console-application, conemu

If I invoke ConEmu from the windows cmd prompt p.e.

```
>%Path_to_ConEmu%/ConEmu64.exe -dir "c:\python37\scripts" -run "pip list"
```

Immediately after the output ConEmu asks to "Press Enter or Esc to close console......"

I don't want to close the console but to stay in `c:\python37\scripts`

How can I do this?

Comment: But the console stays in `c:\python32\scripts`. Don't you want to ask "How may I get opened shell in the directory"? What shell?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, after executing above command I want to keep a command prompt/shell (cmd.exe) opened in `c:\python37\scripts` (I've installed Python 3.7)

Comment: @Maximus, do you have any idea? You are the owner of ConEmu?

Comment: Use `cmd /k`. The `cmd /?` is very useful, recommended ;)

Comment: I use the code it in Total Commander (an icon in the toolbar). This doesn't work cmd \K "%Path_to_ConEmu%\ConEmu64.exe" pip list --outdated - I really don't know.

Comment: @Maximus  `cmd /K pip list --outdated` does work in cmd.exe but I can't find out how to do this in ConEmu.

Comment: And what is the problem? Just run it.

Comment: Look at the your original post. Do you see there "pip list"? So WHY do you try to replace this with "cmd /k ConEmu.exe pip list"??

Comment: @Maximus, Yes, it runs in cmd.exe but I want to run it in ConEmu (my default emulator), in order to copy text etc.

Comment: Please read again my prev comment. You already have almost correct command, why do you want to break working things?

Comment: @Maximus, Sorry that I did not express myself clearly. (1) Yes I see the "pip list" using the command in my original post, however there is no command prompt in this emulator window. I want to stay in the window and insert more commands p.e. "pip list --outdated".  (2) Yes, I can do this using cmd.exe but I do want to use ConEmu (I can copy text in ConEmu and I personalized it to my liking). (3) What I want to do is to create an icon in the toolbar of Total Commander: Clicking on the icon I want it to open ConEmu, launching the command "pip list" and stay in ConEmu with a command prompt.

Comment: `%Path_to_ConEmu%/ConEmu64.exe -dir "c:\python37\scripts" -run "cmd /k pip list"` Isn't it simple?

Comment: @Maximus, If it was that simple why did you think I'd tried for hours and write so much with you and why did not you write it before? To taunt me? ;) I really had no idea. Didn't know that you could use `run` and `cmd` together. I don't work in computer science. btw.. большое спасибо